# Credit card validation

Tags: java, string, int

I need help to convert from a string to int, i've searched
and didnt find anything that can help me with this specific question.

this is what i got so far.. (code down)

- The card has to be 6 digit long (e.g 123456) - got it
- I've isolated each digit of the card number (ones, tens, hundreds...)
- I've combined the first five digits (from the left) of the card using a string.

Now after combining the first 5 digits (e.g 1+2+3+4+5=12345)
i need to MOD this number in 7 (12345%7)

but it keeps giving me the next error -

**java.lang.number.formatexception
for input string: fiveDigits:(in java.lang.number.formatexception)**

Any guidelines on how to fix it will be much appreciated.
Thanks.

```
if(creditCard<=99999||creditCard>=1000000)
         System.out.println("Your credit card is not valid. You cannot buy the ticket");
         else
        {

                ones = creditCard%10;
                tens = (creditCard%100)/10;
                hundreds = (creditCard%1000)/100;
                thousands = (creditCard%10000)/1000;
                tensOfThousands = (creditCard%100000)/10000;
                hunOfThousands = (creditCard%1000000)/100000;

                String fiveDigits = "" + hunOfThousands+tensOfThousands+thousands+hundreds+tens;
                int firstFiveDigits = Integer.parseInt("fiveDigits");
                int remainder = firstFiveDigits%7;


                if(remainder==ones)
                 System.out.println("Your credit card is valid. Bon Voyage!");
                else
                   System.out.println("Your credit card is not valid. You cannot buy the ticket");
```

Comment: You are parsing the String "fiveDigits", not the String represented by the variable fiveDigits. Remove the quotes, and you'll be fine.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the quotes surrounding the variable fiveDigits

int firstFiveDigits = Integer.parseInt(fiveDigits);

Answer (score 0):

```
int firstDigits = (allDigits - allDigits%10)/10;
```

It ain't good but it's better ...

You can operate with "real" CC numbers as strings (as they are quite long) - just get your `allDigitsAsString` as input and then

```
String firstDigitsAsString = allDigitsAsString.substring(0, allDigitsAsString.length() - 1);
int firstDigits = Integer.parseInt(firstDigitsAsString);
```

For bonus points add some imitation call to a payment processor stub.